# Cannot get this button to display correct color after clicked

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So I cannot for the life of me get the button border to display the same color as the hover state. As you can see at the end of the css I put a focus selector on it and nothing. Tried active and same thing. Here is the project in whole, below is the relevant code. https://xvicissitudex.github.io/stratup-landing-page/

```css
     .btn-primary {
      font-weight: 700;
      border-radius: 300px;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      background-color: #F05F44;
      border-color: #F05F44;
    
    }
    
    .btn-primary:hover {
      background-color: #ee4b08;
      border-color: #ee4b08;
      border-width: 4px;
    
    }
    
    .btn-primary:focus {
      background-color: #ee4b08;
      border-color: #ee4b08;
      border-width: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 #ee4b08 ;
    
    }
```

```html
 <button class="btn btn-primary">FIND OUT MORE</button>
```

Comment: It looks to be working with the code you have provided.

Comment: Can't get the button to display the same color as the hover state. I am reding this as you want the same background color in a natural state as you have when hovering. So can you just change `F05F44` to `ee4b08` in the hex color codes??

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems to be functioning as it should be. For demonstration purposes, I changed your click color to blue.

You can use `:active` if you want your button to flash a certain color on click.

However, if you want the button to change color on click and not change until click again then I would use `:focus`

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/bnL9temv/18/) to see the difference between the two pseudo-elements.